# how to find the correct sampling rate for interp1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, resampling, downsampling

i am trying to find the correct sampling rate for interp1 (or decimate or resample) for plotting a number of points in axes obtained by imfreehand..

First i plot something (anything not sine specific)

```
bands=1:20;plot(bands,sin(bands));
hax=gca;
```

[image]

Then draw something with imfreehand on the  axis like this:

```
imfreehand('Closed',0);
```

[image]

I extract the data parts *(size 1x413)*  from imfreehand object and then i try to plot them with the length of the original line but the scaling is wrong ...

```
data=get(hfree); 
xydata=get(data.Children(4)); 
% x=xydata.XData;
y=xydata.YData; 

len=length(y);
x=1:len;
newlen=length(bands);
scale=(len-1)/(newlen-1);
xx=1:scale:len;

yy=interp1(x,y,xx,'spline');

line(1:length(yy),yy(1:length(yy)),...
   'LineWidth',4,...
   'Color',[.8 .8 .8],...
   'Parent',hax);
```

[image]

**Any hints??**

Also, the same results with suggested downsample ..

```
for i=4:1:15 %just testing numbers 

    yy = downsample(y,i);

    h=line(1:length(yy),yy(1:length(yy)),...
        'LineWidth',1.2,...
        'Color',[.8-i/100 .8-i/100 .8-i/100],...
        'Parent',hax);

    if length(bands)==length(yy)
        set(h,'Color',[0 0 0], 'LineWidth',2);
    end

end
```

[image]

**Any hints??** x2

Comment: `interp1` has no "sampling rate" associated with it. You provide a bunch of control points, then a bunch of points you want to interpolate at.  What's going on here is that you are providing points to interpolate with and because the distance between those points increases as you give less points, the way the curve is being drawn is that it simply linearly interpolates in between those points.  You are better off using `upsample`, and `downsample` from the Signal Processing Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/upsample.html, http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/downsample.html

Comment: @rayryeng well i have already tried that but i see the same effect... (in the picture the colored blue is the freehand line and colored black is the subsampled with the same size). You can see the same shift..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well silly of me to forgot to scale properly in interp

```
len=length(y);
newlen=length(bands);
scale=ceil(len/newlen)    

x1=x(1:scale:end)
y1=y(1:scale:end);
h=line(x1,y1,...
        'LineWidth',1.2,...
        'Color',[0 0 0],...
        'Parent',hax);

yyy=interp1(x1,y1,bands,'pchip',nan)

h=line(1:20,yyy,...
        'LineWidth',1.2,...
        'Color',[0 1 1],...
        'Parent',hax);
```

[image]